# Knockout : Update to Text box value is not updating the observable item

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js, two-way-binding

I have an ObservavleArray , which is initialized with two items when the UI loads.

Now there is an add button which pushes new observable item to observable array. This works fine.

But when I edit the values on text box and I expect them to change on underlying observable item, but this does not happen.

Here is the code snippet for that.

```js
 var InventoryViewModel = function() {
     var self = this;
     self.STockItems = ko.observableArray();

     InitializeStock(self);

     self.addItems = function(vm) {
         self.STockItems.push(new ko.observable(''));
     }
     self.ProcessInventory = function(vm) {
         console.log(vm.STockItems());
     };
 }

 var vm = new InventoryViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(vm);


 function InitializeStock(context) {
     context.STockItems.push(new ko.observable('Item1'));
     context.STockItems.push(new ko.observable('Item2'));
 }
```

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-text {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: STockItems">
    <li>
        <span class="input-group">
            <input  data-bind="textInput: $data" />                                       
        </span>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="text-right"> <a data-bind="click:addItems">+ Add more</a></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent" data-bind="click: $root.ProcessInventory">Process Inventory</button>
<pre class='info-text' data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, '\t')">
</pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvza6nu2/1/

**Edit:**
As I am pushing a observable item directly , I guess I do not have to create a wrapper to push the items.

```
function EditableField(initialValue) {
  this.value = ko.observable(initialValue);
}
```

If I must use this wrapper, then why? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables need to be bound to a property in the viewmodel, that's the only way to reference them from the HTML.
$data is a reference to the viewmodel's context rather than the observable itself. It just so happened that in your `foreach` context there was only 1 observable, so it looked like your initial setup was working.

Read all about the binding context [here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

To get it to work properly, you need to push objects into your observableArray, with named properties that will later be referenced from the HTML. Each object in the observableArray becomes a mini-viewmodel in the `foreach` loop.

**Edit**:

1. There's no need to use `new` to create on observable.
2. `$root` refers to the primary viewModel. It's useful to use it when we want to reference it from a child's/descendant's viewModel. In your case, for `ProcessInventory` click, it's not needed since we are already in the primary viewModel context.

```js
 var InventoryViewModel = function() {
     var self = this;
     self.STockItems = ko.observableArray();

     InitializeStock(self);

     self.addItems = function(vm) {
         self.STockItems.push({item : ko.observable('')});
     }
     self.ProcessInventory = function(vm) {
         console.log(vm.STockItems());
     };
 }

 var vm = new InventoryViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(vm);


 function InitializeStock(context) {
     context.STockItems.push({item : ko.observable('Item1')});
     context.STockItems.push({item : ko.observable('Item2')});
 }
```

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.info-text {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: STockItems">
    <li>
        <span class="input-group">
            <input  data-bind="textInput: item" />                                       
        </span>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="text-right"> <a data-bind="click:addItems">+ Add more</a></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-accent" data-bind="click: ProcessInventory">Process Inventory</button>
<pre class='info-text' data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, '\t')">
</pre>
```